# Posting data from EJS to Node.js

Tags: node.js, ejs, fetch-api

*I have an **index.html** EJS rendered by a koa/Node.js app which contains a javascript snippet to post data about the current page to the same app, to an endpoint to save in a database.*

The javascript code ( an AJAX  `fetch POST`) reaches the Node.js endpoint but doesn't transmit any data. I don't see any typo in the code.

[CORRECTION] **indeed a typo with the bodyparser**

```js
# index.js
const Koa = require("koa");
const path = require("path");
const render = require("koa-ejs");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const router = require("./routes/routes.js");

const app = new Koa();

render(app, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "/views"),
  layout: false,
  viewExt: "html",
});

app
  .use(bodyParser())
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods())
  .use(staticCache("./images", { maxAge: 600000 }))
  .listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
```

In the **index.html**, I have a button that triggers a POST request to an endpoint (`/node/insert`) of the koaRouter. The action is to save information about the current page (say, `document.location.href`) in a Postgres database.

```html
# /views/index.html
[...]
<form id="newRow">
  <input type="submit" value="New row">
</form>
[...]
<script type="module" src="fetch.js" async></script>
```

where:

```js
# /views/fetch.js
const data = {
  app: "Node",
  url: document.location.href,
  ...
};

document.getElementById("newRow").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch("/node/insert", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset-UTF-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      }
      return Promise.reject(res);
    })
    .then((res) => console.log("front", res))
    .catch((err) => console.warn(err));
```

Among the routes, I defined an endpoint `/node/insert` to respond to this action:

```js
# routes.js
const koaRouter = require("koa-router");
const router = new koaRouter();

router.post("/node/insert", async (ctx) => {
  console.log("posted", ctx.request.body);   
   ^^^  "posted" is positively printed in terminal after submit

  if (ctx.request.body) {
     return (ctx.response.status = 200)
  } else {
    return (ctx.response.status = 404); <-- check
  }
})
```

*The endpoint "/node/insert" is reached* since I can console.log positively,  but the body isn't passed to the endpoint: `ctx.request.body = {}`. I have the following error:

`"SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0"`

detected from fetch.js (probably because the body is `{}`?).

I don't see what is wrong.

> Note: the Node app runs in a container (`pm2-runtime start index.js`) and use Nginx as reverse proxy, static files server and load-balancer`

Comment: Are you looking for the body parser middleware?

Comment: I did try to add "app.use(bodyparser())" with "bodyparser=require('koa-bodyparser')" but this gives me an error I can't fix: "Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0"

Comment: The Koa route is "router.post("/node/insert", ...)" in the "routes.js" file. Then this is run with containers, so the url is ok I believe (the "post" endpoint responds positively in the terminal if I insert a "console.log", but the body is "{}" ). I added the 404 to show that "ctx.requeset.body" is empty

Comment: [My question turned out to be a rather esoteric typo — what should I do/what should be done?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269605/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const koaJson = require(koa-json);
app.use(koaJson());
```

Comment: This does nothing. I understand It's just a "prettyfier"

Comment: Per the poster, the issue was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo in the bodyparser as Evert pointed and bad positioning of the middleware

`curl --data "app=Node" HTTP://localhost:8000/node` responds normaly.